# Is there a way using python to select an item in the combobox "Region" using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to select the first item of the combobox "Region" with this script **in this website [LINK](https://www.tgr.cl/certificado-pago-deudas-contribuciones-tramite/)** Python + Selenium

[image]

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images':2, 'disk-cache-size': 4096 }
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)

url = 'https://www.tgr.cl/certificado-pago-deudas-contribuciones-tramite/'
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('busqueda'))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='region']/option[text()='REGION DE ANTOFAGASTA']").click()
```

But im getting this Error when Im switching the frame. Output:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="busqueda"]"}
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: The content is inside a frame. Have you switched to the frame?

Comment: No I have not. But still if I try to find the iframe with this script the result is the same:
`driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')`
Any recomendations?

Comment: Please add the code that you've used to switch to frame and what error comes then

Comment: I update the question with the new code and output.

Comment: I don't see any element that's named "busqueda" in the little bit of code you shared, nor in the source of the page you link. Also, this has nothing to do with selecting the option in the select element, as you don't reach that part. The frame you are looking for appears to be called "wp_tgr_frame"

Comment: The problem was that I was selecting what seem to be the iframe of the iframe. So I needed to switch to the one you mention first and it worked! Thanks you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the combobox is the iframe of an iframe. So you needed to switch to the first iframe and after to the his child in that way you will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

All subdocuments like the `<iframe>` your element is in lazyload into existence slower than your entire webpage. It might be best to wait a few seconds, or until Selenium detects the `<iframe>`.

```py
# Wait specifically for that iframe, then switch to it
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

iframe_detector = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_name('busqueda'),
                                                  message="Iframe never loaded!")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_detector)

#Just wait and hope it loads in
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('busqueda'))
```

You may need longer wait times to account for your internet connection.